# Swagger3-ui URL does not working in my Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, api, swagger, swagger-ui

I've tried these urls too

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/

This is my swagger configuration class.

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.faramarz.spring.Covid19RestApi"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfo(
                "TITLE",
                "DESCIPRION",
                "VERSION",
                "TERMS OF SERVICE URL",
                new Contact("NAME", "URL", "EMAIL"),
                "LICENSE",
                "LICENSE URL",
                Collections.emptyList()
        );
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after one day, I fixed that like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebMvc
public class SwaggerDocumentation {

    public static final Contact CONTACT = new Contact("Faramarz", "http://muralitechblog.com/", "https://faramarzaf.github.io/");
    public static final ApiInfo DEFAULT_API = new ApiInfo("swagger", "Swagger Documentation", "1.0", "urn:tos", CONTACT, "Apache 2.0", "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0", new ArrayList<>());
    public static final Set<String> consumes = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("application/json"));
    public static final Set<String> produces = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("application/json"));

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(DEFAULT_API).consumes(consumes).produces(produces);
    }

}
```

```xml
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct url is

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

Add this Annotation

```
@EnableSwagger2
```

Add these two dependencies and remove the above dependency you have been using

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

this will work

Comment: i have added a full class solution above please test it

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .globalOperationParameters(parameters());
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("USER API")
            .contact(new Contact("Your Name", "", "Your Email"))
            .build();
}

private List<Parameter> parameters() {
    List<Parameter> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

    Parameter headParameter = new ParameterBuilder()
            .name("User Restful API")
            .description("")
            .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
            .parameterType("header")
            .required(false)
            .build();

    parameters.add(headParameter);

    return parameters;
}}
```

Please use this Class, just comment your class out and test this

Comment: Completely copied your code, but still doesn't work. I should mention that   http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs works but UI part no.

Comment: after coping my code, adding the dependencies i mentioned did you run mvn clean install?

Comment: yes I changed the dependencies  as you wrote. I'm really confused.

Comment: is it possible to share your screen, probably on Anydesk so that i can see your code

Comment: sure, this is an open source code. https://github.com/faramarzaf/Covid19RestApi

Comment: let me pull the code and push after solving the problem

Comment: i have managed to solve the issue, just create a package called configs, then move your SpringFoxConfig class  tnto the configs package, then run your application, then in your browser visit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html .....this will work

Comment: tapsshore thank you very much, few moment ago finally fixed. check my answer

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali that is okay, at least we reached a solution